# throwing null pointer exception ,want to display content provider save item in list view using base adapter

Tags: android

dear i save the data in content provider and fetch using cursor object and want to display in list view using base adapter but it is throwing "NULL POINTER EXCEPTION " i dont understood ehy bcoz i am showing value in log cat it display and after i store these values in array using for loop ,please take a look in my code, and debug pls where  i m wrong.

```
static String id = null;
static String userName = null;
static String[] usr;
@Override

}
```

Answer (score 1):

You never initialized the array `usr`, so it's still null. Consider adding before the loop:

```
usr = new String[id.length()];
```

Comment: @MByD pls look at my other qus thread related to same appp...throwing array index out of bound..

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6288967/array-index-out-of-bound-want-to-display-content-provider-save-item-in-list-view